# '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str' while fitting the multibomialNB model

Tags: python, string, machine-learning, null, naivebayes

I am getting the following error while fitting the MultinomialNB model.
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'
I have dropped a column which is having null values.

Comment: To get an accurate answer, please edit your question by adding some code in it

Comment: The error is self explanatory. You can reproduce the error by typing into Python repl `3 < "4"`. A < comparison between an `int` and `str` wield yield this error. You will have to either do `str(3)` or `int("4")` if you still want to go ahead making the comparison.